# How to get Message status when loading from history in Smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am using `DeliveryReceiptManager` to get Delivery status its working fine in real time . But later on when i am loading message History with `MamManager` the message does not containg any tag regarding status . Below is the msg xml i get .

```
<forwarded
xmlns='urn:xmpp:forward:0'>
<delay
    xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' stamp='2018-02-09T06:10:05.835+00:00'>
</delay>
<message to='1111@imd/Smack' from='9999@imd/Smack' id='9hrek-100' type='chat'>
    <body>Hello</body>
    <request
        xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/>
    </message>
</forwarded>
```

How can i check whether the message was delivered or not from history ?

And to get Read receipt for message right now i can not find any Documentation for Read receipt ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not your server also archives delivery receipts. If that is not the case then you are out of luck.

Comment: Yeah i am using monitoring plugin. And i can not find any field or table for delivery status . How can i enable this feature on server ? Is there any plugin exists or i have to provide a custom implementation for it . I am currently using `SMACK4.4.2` and `openfire-4.1.4-1.x86_64.rpm`.

Comment: can you please provide some direction . How can i achive this . You wer right MessageArchive not saving the status of message in database.